Simple CMake setup for Gazebo Harmonic fails on Ubuntu Noble
Attempting to link with gz-sim8::core produces CMake errors on Ubuntu Noble but not on Ubuntu Jammy.
CMake script
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(a)
add_executable(b main.cpp)
find_package(gz-sim8 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(b public gz-sim8::core)

Produced error:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (target_link_libraries):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:CPPZMQ::CPPZMQ,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>

  Target "CPPZMQ::CPPZMQ" not found.


CMake Error:
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:CPPZMQ::CPPZMQ,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>

  Target "CPPZMQ::CPPZMQ" not found.


CMake Error:
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:CPPZMQ::CPPZMQ,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>

  Target "CPPZMQ::CPPZMQ" not found.


CMake Error at sr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gz-transport13/gz-transport13-targets.cmake:71 (set_target_properties):
  The link interface of target "gz-transport13::gz-transport13" contains:

    CPPZMQ::CPPZMQ

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  sr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gz-transport13/gz-transport13-config.cmake:137 (include)
  sr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gz-sim8/gz-sim8-config.cmake:94 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)

Full CMake output
To reproduce
docker run -it --rm ubuntu:noble

# Add Gazebo APT repository
apt-get update
apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes wget ca-certificates gnupg lsb-release
wget https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.gpg -O /usr/share/keyrings/pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg] \
http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable $(lsb_release -cs) main" \
    | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list > /dev/null
apt-get update

# Install gz-sim8
apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes libgz-sim8-dev

# Install CMake and compiler
apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes cmake make g++

# Create project
echo 'int main() {}' >main.cpp
cat >CMakeLists.txt  # Paste in CMake script from above, then Ctrl-D

# Attempt to configure
cmake -B build -S .  # Produces errors
```


Workaround
Install dpkg package cppzmq-dev manually. This package is installed automatically only on Jammy.
To solve a related issue regarding TINYXML2::TINYXML2, add the following alias target to CMakeLists.txt:
find_package(tinyxml2 REQUIRED)
add_library(TINYXML2::TINYXML2 ALIAS tinyxml2::tinyxml2)

TinyXML did not have a CMake Find module in Jammy, but it does in Noble, and the target it defines is now named tinyxml2::tinyxml2.

Upstream PR: https://github.com/gazebo-release/gz-transport13-release/pull/9

Seems a real bug in packaging, the PR looks good to fix it.
